# UIWebview not loading the correct localized version of website

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, localization

In my app I have a link in the menu that takes the user to our FAQ page online. I'm using a webview to load the page and so far so good.

But the problem is, my online page auto detects the user language and loads the correct localized version of the page.

If I open safari on the simulator and load my url, it gets redirected to the correct localized version of it, but using UIWebview on the app it loads the english (default) language.

I've done some research online, but couldn't find anything related to this matter.

Is there something I can/need to pass in order to the correct localized version to be loaded?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I'm currently getting the phone language and passing in the URL, but what I'm looking for is for the UIWebview to behave like safari does, by calling the main URL and having the website choose the version based on your language.

Comment: Have you found any solution for same?

Comment: @Dev_Tandel unfortunately I never found out the solution

Comment: i have been trying since a week and still empty handed.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the app supported languages as an array of strings with `[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations];` and compare it with the system language like this:

```
+ (NSString *)preferredLanguage {
    NSString *res = @"en";

    NSArray *appSupportedLanguages = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations];
    NSArray *appleLanguages = [NSLocale preferredLanguages];

    if (appleLanguages && appleLanguages.count > 0) {
        NSString *shortLangId = [appleLanguages.firstObject substringToIndex:2];

        if ([appSupportedLanguages containsObject:shortLangId]) {
            res = shortLangId;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

The reason i'm using the shortened version here is that iOS 9 changed some languages' ids and it breaks my app — you should probably make some minor changes here. Nevertheless, this method allows you to get the language id you can use to open the proper FAQ page either like `https://.../faq_fr.htm` or with some server-side processing like `https://...?lang=fr`.

Comment: this is what I'm currently doing, but what I'm actually looking for is to make the request to my page and have the page loaded in the correct version instead of passing the URL with the language in it, the same way safari does it if you open it in the simulator.
I was assuming uiwebview would work just like safari, but it doesn't seem that way